# PDO::FETCH_CLASS not working "because class not found"

Tags: php, pdo

So I use the composer autoloader, everything works fine except the class I want to use in PDO::FETCH_CLASS.
Here is the index :

```
<?php
use Tristan\TableauDynamique\Controller\Controller;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

Controller::listProducts();
```

Controller class :

```
<?php

namespace Tristan\TableauDynamique\Controller;

use Tristan\TableauDynamique\Model\ProductsManager;

class Controller
{
    public static function listProducts() : void
    {
        $productManager = new ProductsManager;

        $products = $productManager->getAllProducts();

        require 'views/tabView.php';
    }
}
```

ProductsManager class :

```
<?php
namespace Tristan\TableauDynamique\Model;

use Tristan\TableauDynamique\Classes\Product;

class ProductsManager extends Manager
{

    public function getAllProducts() : array
    {
        $pdo = $this->dbConnect();
        try {
            $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 20");
            $products = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Product');
            return $products;
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Erreur requête SQL :' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Product class :

```
<?php

namespace Tristan\TableauDynamique\Classes;

class Product
{
    public int $id;

    public int $name;

    public int $price;

    public int $address;

    public int $city;

}
```

And I get this error :
*Fatal error: Class "Product" not found in D:\dev\PHP\TP\Tableau_dynamique\src\model\ProductsManager.php on line 15*

The thing I don't understand is that I can create new Product in the method "getAllProducts" if I want to and it works, but PDO can't find the Product class...

Comment: Instead of `'Product'`, try `Product::class`

Comment: It was a namespace problem indeed, Product::class works. Thanks !